# Which is better? Using a while loop or putting call to main function at the end of every other function definition

Tags: java, while-loop

```
MainScreen() {
    DisplayUI();
    GetInput();
}
DisplayUI {
    // prints press 1 for this 2 for that etc...
}
GetInput() {
    // Gets input and calls the next approprite function according to that input e.g 1 for login etc...
    // e.g 
    if (input == 1) {
    Login();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    if (input == x) {
    somefunc();
    }
    // if the user enters an input that is not accounted for call this function
    MainScreen();
}

Login() {
    // do some stuff
    MainScreen();
}
somefunc() {
    // do some stuff
    MainScreen();
}

main {
    MainScreen();
}
```

Is there any draw back of using above approach(having MainScreen(); at the end of every function implentation?)?

Over this(using a while loop and removing MainScreen(); from end of every function)

Which one is better? In either case I want to run my program indefinitely. I used the above approach and my program is working flawlessly is there any need to change my code?

```
main {
    while(true){
        MainScreen();   // 
    }
}
```

Comment: This.. this isn't Java.

Comment: java !!! they didn't publish this updated version yet...how you found this secret !!

Comment: Ummmm.... I'm sure there would be some sort of `stack overflow` at some point... (?)

Answer (score 3):

Using a loop is definitely better.

Having a `MainScreen();` at the end of each function violates the DRY principle (eg you will have to find all the places you put that statement if you decide to change that function-name).

Also, there is no need for recursion, so dont use it.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive method will result in a very large call stack, and inevitably lead to a `StackOverflow`.

Therefore I would recommend the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function, your program has to know where to continue execution after it completes the function. Let's take a simple pseudo-code program to illustrate this:

```
function HelloWorld() {
    print "Hello, World!\n";
}

function Main() {
    print "1... "; HelloWorld();
    print "2... "; HelloWorld();
    print "3... "; HelloWorld();
}

Main();
print "Good bye.\n";
```

The output of this program will be the fairly simple

```
1... Hello, World!
2... Hello, World!
3... Hello, World!
Good bye.
```

In other words, the program calls Main().

Main, in turn, prints "1...", calls HelloWorld, and continues execution so prints "2...", cals HelloWorld, and continues execution so prints "3...", calls HelloWorld a final time, continues execution so exits.

At that point, the program continues execution after its call to Main, so prints a farewell and then exits.

In other words, for each function that you call, your program has to remember where to continue in the calling function. It does this by maintaining what is named a *call stack*.

Whenever you call a function, a *call frame* is pushed on top of that call stack. This call frame contains, among other things, the memory address of the next instruction to execute and the values of the variables that were in scope at the time of the function call. When a function exits, the topmost call frame is popped off the callstack. The program jumps to the memory address stored in that frame, and happily goes on about its business.

So the call stack **grows** with every function you call and **shrinks** with every function that gets a change to complete.

In our little program above, the stack will never contain more than three frames (which is a ridiculous small amount):

1. Initially, the call frame is empty. (stack size = 0)
2. We call `Main()` - push a frame (stack size = 1)

   1. We call `print` - push a frame (stack size = 2)
   2. `print` exits - pop a frame (stack size = 1)
   3. Repeat steps 2.1 and 2.2 two more times.
3. `Main()` exits - pop a frame (stack size = 0)
4. The program exits (stack size=0)

Now let's see what happens if we rewrite our program like this:

```
function HelloWorld() {
    print "Hello, World\n";
}

function Main () {
    while (true) {
        HelloWorld();
    }
}

Main();
```

This creates an infinite loop of calling HelloWorld and we'll be greeting the world until the universe ends (or the user presses Ctrl+C or has a power outage).

What happens to the call stack?

1. Begin program. (stack size = 0)
2. Call `Main()` - push a frame (stack size = 1)
3. Call `HelloWorld()` - push a frame (stack size = 2)
4. `HelloWorld()` exits - pop a frame (stack size = 1)
5. Go back to step 3 and continue from there.

The call stack alternates between having 1 and 2 frames, which is very reasonable considering that the program will never end.

Now, instead of using a `while` loop, let's call `Main()` at the end of `HelloWorld()`:

```
function HelloWorld() {
    print "Hello, World!\n";
    Main();
}

function Main() {
    HelloWorld();
}

Main();
```

Superficially, this creates the same endless loop where we print a greeting to the world until the end of days. But under the hood something different happens. Can you see it yet?

1. Begin program (stack size = 0)
2. Call Main() - push a frame (stack size = 1)
3. Call HelloWorld() - push a frame (stack size = 2 )
4. Call Main() - push a frame (stack size = 3)
5. Call HelloWOrld() - push a frame (stack size = 4).

... I'm sure you get the pattern.

Eventually your program will crash, loudly complaining about a stack overflow.